# CreateJs MovieClip Instance name

Tags: html, movieclip, createjs, flash-cc

Hi Guys (sorry for my bad english), 
I've stuck with this in a week, is it possible to get the movieclip instance name with createJS (I've put the movieclip manually on the stage and I give it an instance name), in AS3 I can use `movieclip.name` to get the instance name, how can I do that in createJS, when I use `this.movieclipName.name` it always return `null` in console log, do You have any suggestion? Thanks for Your help?

Comment: Just curious: why do you need the "name"? The instance name you use in Flash becomes the reference name in the parent element (exportRoot.myInstanceName).

Comment: Thanks for asking Lanny, I want to doing a loop to scan/read all the movieclip from parent with special name like `object1`, `object2`, etc. I'm thinking to doing something like this:                                                         `for (var k in this){  /*get all movieclip instances name */ if(this[k].name.substring(0,7)=='object'){                                                  //do something, like put it in array }}` but it didn't work, when I'm trying to see the name of the movieclip it always return null in the console log.

Comment: When doing a loop you can reference it like (where i is the index): var myobject = stage["object"+i].

Answer (score 0):

@Ferry thank You very much  for Your solution. finally I figured it out, We can't get the instance name of the object by `myObject.name` because the name of the object is not signed previously (it looks like the **instance name** not same as **name** in html5). that's why it always giving a `null`. This is my script to get all the instances name of my objects.

```
for (var a = 0; a <= maxObject - 1; a++) {
   var myObjectName = 'object' + (a + 1);
   var myObject = this[arrObject[a]];

   myObject.name = myObjectName;
}
```

Thank you guys for all of your respon.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem using:

```
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
this["m" + i].addEventListener("click", clickme.bind(this));
this["m" + i].hamdy=i;}
```

so you can use var hamdy to pass any change in clickme funaction.